# If I connect to mysql, how can I import my modules by python?

Tags: python, mysql, module, pymysql

If I want to connect to mysql, here is my code. However, I do not want 'admin','root' and etc, shown below. I think I can create my own modules and then import them. However, I have no idea what the function will look like and how to import it. Thanks in advance.

```
db_new1 = pymysql.connect(database='byt',
                      user='root',
                      password='admin',
                      host='localhost',
                      port=3306)
cursor_new1 =db_new1.cursor()
```

Comment: Are you saying you want an external source for these parameters? Its common to have a config file file read by [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) or other things like json or yaml. Its not so common to import a module with configuration information in it because you usually want to keep this type of information out of the python module path where anybody could get ahold of it.

Comment: why not use environment variables? I agree, you shouldn't have to hardcode db credentials in code. You can store them in other places, for ex. environment or even better in a secrets store that you can query them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way you can do this is by having a config.py file in which you can store all the data you need as shown below

config.py

```
database = 'byt'
user = 'root'
password = 'admin'
host = 'localhost'
port = 3306
```

Then in your main file you can import the config.py file as a whole or only specific variables (this is recommended to avoid namespace errors and clashes)

main.py

```
from config import database, user, password, host, port

db_new1 = pymysql.connect(database=database, user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port)
cursor_new1 =db_new1.cursor()
```

If you're using git, please be sure to add `config.py` to `.gitignore` to avoid information leak.